# Symple Python script running on API

Tags: python, api, server

I need to setup a very light server consisting of a Python script that is invoked by an API call. The pipeline is the following:

1) The front-end sends an API call that has several arguments.

2) The Python script is invoked via the API arguments, does something, and returns a JSON with some data.

Seems easy, but I'm stuck on how exactly make this happen. I know Python, but have a little experience in servers, setting up a server, and talking to a script via the server. Would appreciate a step-by-step guide, or a link to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a really basic script to get you started with [Flask server](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print(request.args)
    return jsonify(["Hello", "world"])

app.run(port=5001)
```

`request.args` are the arguments to the request as a dictionary. You can do whatever you want with them, then return a JSON as shown.

[Flask installation instructions are here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/#installation)

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to go with **Django** (Python's high level web framework that has the support of automatically generated ADMIN interface) and **Django rest framework**  (for Rest APIs development with ADMIN dashboard support).

https://www.djangoproject.com/start/ and http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/ are official links for **Django** and **Django rest framework** respectively.

> **Video**: you can also watch 
>   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KsLHt3D_jsE (trydjango 1.8). There are other videos from the same YouTuber for different Python/Django versions.

Once you are done with a simple **Django** based website then you can host it on [Pythonanywhere](https://pythonanywhere.com/). [Deploying an existing Django project on Pythonanywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/) best describes the steps to deploy your **Django** web application.

> I have also used these steps to deploy my website while learning **Django**. It's http://rishikesh67.pythonanywhere.com/.
>
> I have also designed  Rest APIs using **Django rest framework** in this website. You can few of the API endpoints at http://rishikesh67.pythonanywhere.com/hygull/api/.

There are other ways also that you can choose for your need but I suggested above as I can help to bring you on the right track.

Please comment if you need more help in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I will start with Flask, as its more lightweight, and if not successful, I'll switch to Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice), it's easy to develop just like Flask, and easy to deploy to AWS.

```
$ pip install chalice
$ chalice new-project helloworld && cd helloworld
$ cat app.py

from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name="helloworld")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return {"hello": "world"}

$ chalice local
...
http://localhost:8000

$ chalice deploy
...
https://endpoint/dev

$ curl https://endpoint/api
{"hello": "world"}
```

Some suggested Django, as I've been writing Django apps for many years, it has bigger learning curve comparing to Chalice/Flask since it's a much bigger framework (the best framework, far superior than any PHP frameworks). If you are keen to just get started on very simple APIs, I'd suggest you to start with Chalice/Flask.

If you are a python veteran and find learning Django a piece of cake then I recommend using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), which works well with Django's ORM and makes standard REST operations easy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll go with Flask for now.